# MS SQL Operand type clash: date is incompatible with bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to solve a question on HackerRank using the Tabibitosan method that I read about. Here is a link to the question if you want to read it:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/projects/problem

Here is my error:
Line 1 Operand type clash: date is incompatible with bigint

Here is my code:

```
SELECT MIN(start_date), MAX(end_date)
FROM (
    SELECT
        start_date, end_date,
        dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY start_date) AS rn,
        start_date - dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY start_date) AS grouping
    FROM projects
) AS r
GROUP BY grouping
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC, MIN(start_date) ASC;
```

There may be other issues with my code but you don't need to fix those since I'm still learning and figuring things out but I can't solve this error and searching has not helped.

Table:

```
Task_ID, Int
Start_date, date
End_date, date
```

Date format: 2015-10-31

I'm not sure why the code isn't working since the goal is basically the same as the date section of where I found the Tabibitosan Method:
https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915680

Comment: Date, unlike datetime and smalldatetime, is incompatible with the integer types and arithmetic operations. You should use the date functions instead.

Comment: Is your question about orable or mssql? I think the problem is you can subtract a number to a date.

Comment: It's about MS SQL. Everything that shows examples of the Tabibitosan method shows as Oracle though for some reason but it works in MS SQL too. 
@Larnu solved my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `start_date - dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY start_date)`. The error is telling you the problem here; but you can't subtract a `bigint` value from a `date`. You need to use `DATEADD`. So replace the expression  above with:

```
DATEADD(DAY,-(dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY start_date)),start_date)
```